# Removing NA category from grouped bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, na

I am currently working with survey data with 250 columns. A sample of my data looks like this:

```
q1 <- factor(c("yes",NA,"no","yes",NA,"yes","no","yes"))
q2 <- factor(c("Albania","USA","Albania","Albania","UK",NA,"UK","Albania"))
q3 <- factor(c(0,1,NA,0,1,1,NA,0))
q4 <- factor(c(0,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,0,0))
q5 <- factor(c("Dont know","Prefer not to answer","Agree","Disagree",NA,"Agree","Agree",NA))
q6 <- factor(c(1,NA,3,5,800,NA,900,2))
sector <- factor(c("Energy","Water","Energy","Other","Other","Water","Transportation","Energy"))

data <- data.frame(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,sector)
```

I have created a function to loop through all 250 columns and create grouped bar charts where x axis shows sectors, y axis shows percentage distribution of answers and fill is the underlying column from data. Below you can see the code for the function:

```
by_sector <- lapply(names(data), function(variable) {
  ggplot(
    data = data,
    mapping = aes(x=sector,fill = data[[variable]])
  ) +
    geom_bar(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]), position="dodge") +
    labs(x = variable, y = "% of total", fill = "Response", caption = paste("Total =", sum(!is.na(data[[variable]])))) +
    geom_text(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..], label=scales::percent(..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..],accuracy = 0.1) ),
              stat="count", position=position_dodge(1), vjust=0.5)+
    #scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent")+
    scale_fill_discrete(na.translate = FALSE) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
    coord_flip()
  
})
```

As you can see from image below, since I use data columns as fill, there is transparent NA category showing up. I want to remove that category from grouped bars.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ruxm.png)

I tried couple of things:
`scale_fill_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)` This just removed NA from legend not from grouped bars.
`fill = subset(data,!is.na(data[[variable]]))` This didn't work
`ggplot(data=na.omit(data[[variable]]))` This didn't work neither.

Is there a way to modify my code for barplots so that NA category doesn't show up as a bar in the graph? Thank you very much beforehand!

Comment: Have you tried `data = subset(data, !is.na(data[[variable]]))` inside the `ggplot` call?

Comment: Yes, this throws an error as well.

Comment: Try  `data = filter(data, !is.na({{variable}}))`

Comment: Thank you Julien. This produces the graph but NA categories are still there

Comment: I've run the code and I don't see any `NA` on the charts

Comment: Do you mean that the percentages take into account the `NA` and you don't want that?

Comment: Yes,exactly. I still see percentages for NAs in the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to aggregate your data outside of `ggplot()` which makes it easier to debug, removes the duplicated computations inside the code and makes it easy to drop the NA categories if desired.

Additionally, I moved the plotting code to a separate function which also allows for easier debugging by e.g. running the code for just one example.

Finally note, that I switched to the `.data` pronoun as the recommend way to use column names passed as strings.

Showing only the plots for two of the problematic columns:

**EDIT** Fixed a small bug by removing the NA values before aggregating instead of doing that afterwards.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

plot_fun <- function(variable) {
  total <- sum(!is.na(data[[variable]]))
  
  data <- data |> 
    filter(!is.na(.data[[variable]])) |> 
    group_by(across(all_of(c("sector", variable)))) |> 
    summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop_last") |> 
    mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) |> 
    ungroup()
  
  ggplot(
    data = data,
    mapping = aes(x = sector, y = pct, fill = .data[[variable]])
  ) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    labs(
      x = variable, y = "% of total", fill = "Response",
      caption = paste("Total =", total)
    ) +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        label = scales::percent(pct, accuracy = 0.1)
      ),
      position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = 0.5
    ) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
    coord_flip()
}

by_sector <- lapply(names(data), plot_fun)


by_sector[c(3, 6)]
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly. Sorry to bother you but I have a questions: Do you know how I can modify the code so that I can include survey weights to the charts? weights are given by another column